# qemu displays and hangs with message 'booting from harddisk '

Tags: qemu

I'm using Debian image with QEMU. Installation works well with below 
command.

```sh
ISO_FILE="debian-buster-DI-alpha5-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso"
DISK_IMAGE="debian.img"
SPICE_PORT=5924

qemu-system-x86_64 \
    -cdrom "${ISO_FILE}" \
        -drive format=raw,if=pflash,file=/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd,readonly \
        -drive file=${DISK_IMAGE:?} \
        -enable-kvm \
        -m 2G \
        -smp 2 \
        -cpu host \
        -vga qxl \
        -serial mon:stdio \
        -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
        -net nic \
        -spice port=${SPICE_PORT:?},disable-ticketing \
        -device virtio-serial-pci \
        -device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
        -chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,name=vdagent
```

But when I start the image again with command like

```sh
DISK_IMAGE="debian.img"
SPICE_PORT=5924

qemu-system-x86_64 \
        -drive format=raw,if=pflash,file=/usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd,readonly \
        -drive file=${DISK_IMAGE:?} 
        -enable-kvm \
        -m 2G \
        -smp 2 \
        -cpu host \
        -vga qxl \
        -serial mon:stdio \
        -net user,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 \
        -net nic \
        -spice port=${SPICE_PORT:?},disable-ticketing \
        -device virtio-serial-pci \
        -device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
        -chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,name=vdagent \
        -snapshot
```

QEMU stuck at `booting from harddisk` . Any thoughts on how resolve this and move 
forward?

Comment: Seems you are using same `drive`configuration used to boot an iso image but it's not. Try something simple like `qemu-system-x86_64 -hda debian.img -m 2G`. Also, seems  `kvm` command [is preferred](https://linuxwebdevelopment.com/run-debian-qemu-kvm-virtual-machine-using-ubuntu-debian/) over `qemu-system-x86_64`.

Comment: thanks, let me try this simple command.

Comment: "kvm" is not preferred (at least not by the upstream QEMU project). It's just a wrapper script that runs qemu-system-x86_64 with the -enable-kvm option, which the command line here is already using. Some distros provide this sort of wrapper script for convenience or backward compatibility, but there's no particular reason to use it.